# Enumerable.Except Problem

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone explain why this doesn't work like I think it should.

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
    Console.WriteLine(number);

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 2
 2.1
 2.3
 2.4
 2.5
*/
```

What I would expect is 2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5. Why would except return a distinct list? Is this a bug?

Update:

Ok, totally missed that point in the docs. Funny 4 people respond with the same answer. You would think you would just up vote the guy who answered it first.:)

Comment: @James: I added a way to do what you want, btw, which I figured is probably more useful to you than "no, it doesn't work that way". ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was going to ask that next but you beat me too it. No way to give you extra brownie points but thank you.

Comment: That's okay. My friend just made me brownies, so I'm stuffed! ;)

Comment: Please read [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2011/08/08/why-enumerableexcept-might-not-work-the-way-you-might-expect) famous blog to understand the internals of `Enumerable.Except()` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why would except return a distinct list? Is this a bug?

Nope. `Except` produces a **set difference**. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

To do what you want, just use `Where` to filter the values appropriately. For example:

```
"abcdddefffg".Where(e => !"cde".Contains(e));       // Produces "abfffg".
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the correct behaviour. The `Except` method is documented to return the *set* difference of the two IEnumerable arguments. Since by definition, sets cannot contain duplicate elements, these are eliminated in the result. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Because "Except" is a "set" function, and the concept of a "set" is defined as a unique list of items. In other words, sets by definition cannot contain duplicates.