# Manually removing items from a collection vs using Enumerable.Except C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections, equality

To remove objects from a List of custom objects using Except method requires you to implement a IEqualityComparer on the object. But is it bad just to remove the objects in a normal foreach loop?

I understand the concept of the IEqualityComparer and using Except but I couldn't get it to work for some reason so I just removed the items manually. Is this considered bad programming?

EDIT: using the manual way id have to override Equals and GetHashcode polluting my view model - I guess that's bad?

Comment: Nothing's wrong if you do the manual as long as it works as expected. If you don't want to pollute the viewmodel you can use `list1.Where(!list2.Any(x.What == y.What))`

Answer (score 1):

In general, one should avoid making changes to a collection while enumerating.

I'm not **entirely** sure what your original problem is, or why you need to remove elements in such a way, but you're over-complicating the problem. If I understand it right, and you are in fact using a `List<T>` where T is a custom type. If this is the case, then simply use a LINQ query to get the values you want from the list.

```
var newList = oldList.Where(x => x.PropertyName != unwantedValue);
```

You could use `Enumerable.Except`, but it should be noted that `Enumerable.Except` returns a **set**, which is to say, no duplicate values are allowed.

Also, it should be noted that overriding `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` does not pollute the viewmodel, as far as I know.

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx

[Enumerable.Except Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669709/enumerable-except-problem)

Comment: its illegal to change a collection while enumerating and will cause runtime exception.

Comment: that wouldn't be enumerating through it, that's iterating through it. Enumeration would use/require the "Enumerator" pattern

Comment: The `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()` and `Current` :-)